# Iphone PageCurlTransition like a book?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hy, i want to make a pagecurltransition like in a book, when i press one button is curlup and i want to see while the transition is beeing made the next page.
And for curldown i want the transition view to be with the next page. Like when i move pages in a book.
The transition works fine but the problem is that i want my instruction to be executed while the transition is beeing done.
The problem is that mywebview loads the text after the transition is done. Here is the code for my transition:

> ```
> [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
>                            duration:1.0
>                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
>                            animations:^{
>                                     [self.theWebView loadHTMLString:text baseURL:nil];
>                            completion:NULL
> ];
> ```
>
> Even if i put the loadHtmlString command before transition it doesn't work like i want.
>
> ```
>        [UIView transitionFromView:mycurentview 
>                                   toView:mynextview 
>                                   duration:1.0 
>                                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
>                                   completion:nil
>                              }
> ```

I've tried this but it doesn't make the animation. It changes from view to view with out animation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of page animation frameworks on github. Here is a good one:

https://github.com/ole/leaves

Comment: I just want something simple, i don't want to the animation to recognize the mouse movement ore something like that, i just want to under the page i flip the next page ( in a transitioncurlup) and in a transition curldown i want to se new page coming from up. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

My last answer was dumb and I apologize for it. I have found that the new UIPageViewController allows really terrific page curling. Erica Sadun has a new book coming out that includes sections on this. Her test code is [here](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-), and look at chapter 5.